# Symfony2 Environment Configuration

Tags: symfony, configuration, environment

I have a Symfony2 application with JS+PHP files that should access

```
"http://localhost/blahblah"
```

when on my development machine, but

```
"http://mydomain.com/blahblah"
```

when I push them to the production server. What's the appropriate way to configure these domains in Symfony2, to avoid manually changing the files with each server push?

Answer (score 0):

I think the better is create a virtual host in your local machine and add these hosts mydomain.com/blahblah www.mydomain.com
In your host file, in linux are in /etc/hosts windows system32\drivers\etc\hosts ( i guess )
When you want to see production site you can comment those lines in your host file

Comment: Clever solution, but I don't know if this will work, since technically mydomain.com/ maps to localhost/mydomain/web/app_dev.php/